# Cleaning mold from windows

Tags: vw, golf, cold-weather

This been a quite humid winter here in Finland, and temps have been going over and below zero a lot of times. Something, that at least in the area were I live wasn't common.

I just notice than some mold has grown in the rear windows of my car. I don't think there is any leaks or anything, but every time temps go over zero the environment go incredible humid because all the snow around thawing.

I've asked a local auto hardware store if they have anything for mold and they've recommended me [this](http://www.starbrite.com/item/mildew-stain-remover?category_id=570).

Is there any better alternative?

I'm thinking to just brush the mold and then try to vacuum the residue. Would I do something else?

Thanks!

PS/ For some of you picture better where the problem is located… on the rear windows, on this kind of velvet that protect the window from the frame itself when it's rolling up and down. The glass of the window doesn't go all the way down by design, so the mold has developed in that part of the frame that even if you roll down the window, the glass is still around.

Comment: Use the a/c - helps keep moisture inside the car under control.

Comment: @SolarMike not really. The amount is so great that the A/C usually isn't able to handle it. Not to mention that sometimes I don't travel that far…

Comment: So the short trips are the issue, the a/c system is usually sized correctly.

Comment: I guess… However, here in the nordics we have interior heaters that you can install in your car and thaw the interior when you park the car on your space. You usually have a plug in your space to connect it the engine heater and a plug inside that connect to the same circuit. The problem is that building companies usually don't want you do use those interior heaters because they use a lot of electricity. Even if it's just for two hours.

Comment: Anyhow… my question is more related to how to get rid of the mold now, than to how to prevent it.

Comment: 5% plain bleach in water (20 to 1), 10% (10 to 1) for heavy mold. Save your money, that's all that is in most mold sprays.

Comment: @Moab wouldn't the bleach discolor things? Where the mold has develop seems to be some kind of black velvet.

Comment: Read the bottle of commercial products, its bleach, that why 5%solution, not strong enough to discolor anything, been saving me money for 40 years. I also use it a cleaning solution for kitchen and bathroom, hardly ever buy overpriced retail products. Learn what they are and make your own, been working for me for over 40 years.

Comment: @Moab the velvet is black, the mold is some other color. For that reason I could see it on the black velvet? 

Comment: No, bleach is not what what you want to use to clean mold (although that is a common urban myth).  Bleach removes the surface layer, leaving the root structures intact, which is why the mold keeps coming back so quickly.  Mold sprays with bleach as the only active ingredient are just designed to sell you more mold spray.

Comment: So… what do we need to use them? @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket ??

Answer (score 0):

Killing mold depends on the type of mold, and different molds require different things to kill them, which also depends on the type of surface they are on.

## Chemicals

There are a variety of commercial and retail mold removal products around, and there's just as much variety in how effective they are. Just doing an online search, here's a page that has a variety of options of chemical sprays.

> Best Overall: RMR-86 Instant Mold & Mildew Stain Remover at Amazon
>   "It works on nearly any surface and promises to remove stains in 15 seconds."
>
> Best for Shower: Skylarlife Mold & Mildew Gel Stain Remover at Amazon
>   "It’s a gel so it doesn’t run down the walls like liquid versions."
>
> Best for Bathroom: Tilex Mold and Mildew Remover Spray at Amazon
>   "Kills mold and other bacteria like staph, strep, and even fungus."
>
> Best for Fabric: Micro Balance EC3 Laundry Additive at Amazon
>   "An all-natural product that you add to your regular laundry detergent."
>
> Best for Wood: Concrobium Mold Control Household Cleaners at Amazon
>   "Works on boats, decks, attics, and more."
>
> Best for Concrete: Wet and Forget Moss Mold Mildew Remover at Amazon
>   "Use the formula to wet the affected area and then forget it."
>
> Best Natural: CleanSmart Daily Surface Cleaner at Amazon
>   "Non-toxic option for use on a daily basis."

https://www.thespruce.com/best-mold-removers-4583978

## Natural options

I've found that hydrogen peroxide (H2O2) works really well on a variety of molds, including black mold. It has a chemical reaction that can't be avoided with the mold cells, similar to how it reacts when cleaning out a cut. It bubbles, releasing oxygen (O2) and water, which means there's really no cleanup, except for removing the debris of the mold itself.

Using too much bleach on a mold can actually cause it to go into a type of hibernation mode that makes it look like it's dead, but isn't. It'll eventually come back as if it never left. And getting the right amount of bleach on mold is generally a secret that keeps mold removal companies in business.

There are other non-hazardous chemicals that can be used to remove mold, with a variation on how well they work and what types of mold they work best on. These are inexpensive and easily acquired, since you might already have them.

1. Hydrogen Peroxide
2. Vinegar
3. Baking soda

https://www.maids.com/cleaning-hacks/3-non-toxic-ways-clean-mold-natural-cleaners/

## Another list

Here's another list of mold killing options. Some are duplicates and it varies between harsh chemicals and natural removers.

> Bleach
>   Borax
>   Vinegar
>   Ammonia
>   Hydrogen peroxide
>   Detergent
>   Baking soda
>   Tea tree oil
>   Grapefruit seed extract

https://moldpedia.com/mold-removal

## Identification

The first thing to removing mold is to figure out what type it is, as best as possible, and then do an online search from there. There's likely a lot of information about how exactly to remove it, which will likely include one or multiple of the products listed above to kill it.

This site seems to cover a good number of common molds, but it's by far a comprehensive list. It includes descriptions of what the mold is and does, and even has pics to show exactly what it looks like. Beware: if you're squeamish, this might not be such a fun read for you, but there's nothing too horrible about it.

https://www.wideopencountry.com/the-12-types-of-mold-how-to-recognize-the-most-common-types-in-your-home/